# How to make chapter page in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I am finding some solution in website.

Before beginning document, type the following:

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
    \vfill
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill
    \end{frame}
}
```

And when I need some chapter page, I can put it by typing

```
\section{text}
```

However, the following code is failed:

```
\section{\textit{Chap. 1} \color{black}{text}}
```

Can someone let me know how to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to make the commands `\textit{}` and `\color{}{}` to robust commands. The following example will help you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox,lipsum}

\robustify{\textit}
\robustify{\color}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
    \vfill
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{text}
Test first section.
\clearpage

\section{\textit{Chap. 1} \color{black}{text}}
Test second section with color changed.

\end{document}
```

I have used the `\robustify{}` command of the `etoolbox` package for fixing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise not to use formatting commands as arguments to `section`, `author` and similar fields. This can break things, as these are not only used to print on the slides but also to create bookmarks, document properties and so on. And even if the pdf viewer on your computer might be able to deal with this, you never know if it break things on the computer you are presenting with.

To circumference such problems, put all formatting commands in places like the section page definition.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{section page}{fg=blue}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
    \vfill
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{section page}
        \usebeamerfont{title}%
        \textit{Chap. \thesection~}%
                {\color{black} \insertsectionhead}\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{text}
\begin{frame}
    Test first section.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]